# Python: error while trying to expand Scrollbar widget using Text widget ( using grid layout)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a text box having h scrollbar on its side.

How can I expand it top to bottom ?

(other widgets are expanded using `sticky = N + S + E + W`, but got an error:

> TypeError: must be str, not Scrollbar

this is example code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.grid(row=0, column=0)

S = Scrollbar(root)
S.grid(row=0, column=1)
S.config(command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to a naming conflict: you have named your scrollbar the same way as the `S` tkinter constant.

I advise you to do `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import *`, this way the tkinter constant `S` will be `tk.S`, so there won't be confusion with the variables you define.